# In The Real Adventures of Jonny Quest, how did Surd's physical appearance change?

Tags: the-real-adventures-of-jonny-quest

In the show *The Real Adventures of Jonny Quest*, how did Surd's physical appearance change?

Before Surd had a normal older man's face with a beard and minimal movement of hands, but in season 2, he appears to have zero mobility with a fully wrinkled older man's face.

Race says it is because of Surd's Chicago nerve gas. However, as per Season 1 show, it ends up Surd with Season 1's looks, not the Season 2.

There is no explanation anywhere online that caused the change.

Comment: Thanks for edit @TheLethalCarrot.
Hoping to get an answer from community :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found some information at http://questfan.com/Page/The_Real_Adventures_of_Jonny_Quest.html that helps to explain. First, Surd was not the only character whose design was changed. Most of the character designs and voices were modified between the first and second seasons (although Surd retained his voice actor of Frank Welker). As to the reasons why the change happened:

> The second season episodes were intended to be broadcast as a separate series, but this plan was negated following the Time-Warner acquisition of Hanna-Barbera.

....

> The Japan-based Mook Studios exclusively animated the second season.

....

> Second season changes prompted Hanna-Barbera to buy out the first cast's contracts and hire new actors.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense now. If the season was intended as a new show, Race mentioning Surd's Chicago nerve gas adds up.